What’s the name of this horror movie where a girl dies and comes back to life evil?
I remember a movie that I saw the trailer and coming attractions for when I was little. Maybe in 2008-2013?
It was a horror movie. A teenaged girl gets killed at a party by hitting her head, I think her temple. And the other teens hide it.
I remember someone saying

“everyone thinks she ran away”

or

“everyone’s gonna think she just ran away”

The girl somehow comes back to life and becomes evil and a killer. I don’t know if she was a succubus (like Jennifer’s Body) or something else.
Everyone was shocked when she turned up at school completely fine and very much alive despite dying the night before.

Reminds me a bit of All Cheerleaders Die, but not exactly.

It could be the horror film Tamara (2005).

After attempting to cast a love spell but not having the guts to actually spill her blood to complete the ritual, Tamara is taken in by a prank by her vengeful classmates, pretending to be Bill so that they can humiliate her on camera. In the commotion, however, Tamara is killed by accident, forcing the kids to hide her body and pretend that nothing happened. Briefly, it seems to have worked.
Problem is, that blow to her head was just the thing to complete Tamara's ritual. She comes Back from the Dead looking better than ever, equipped with the power to read and control people's minds and perceptions with only a touch. And she is madder than hell.
TV Tropes - Tamara

Specifically, she dies when her head hits a table too hard. The trailer shows this moment, along with her being buried afterwards and then showing up in class to the shock of those who were there.





The film includes the line (at the 31 minute mark, shortly after she dies)

If we all keep our mouths shut, everyone will think she ran away.


A very good find. I've taken the liberty of adding in the relevant line from the transcript
